# simple IF statement if value are same

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

Hi am looking for simple if statement logic to show result if the value is same.

I have data comming from my model and have listed this is the view, which shows in a table.

On my 3rd column i want to show a green tick or red cross based on the other 2 column, they are both numbers, if the values are the same then it will show green, else it will show red.

This is my data that i get from model, PK and PartNum.

```
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pk)
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartNum)
```

This is how i started the if statement, but unsure how am going to do it:

```
   @if (item.Pk ....//Confused how it will work here)
   {
   <i class="fa fa-check-circle green"></i>
   }
    else
    {
   <i class="fa fa-check-circle red"></i>
   }
```

Any ideas or will it be easier to do this in the model.

Full view:

```
 @if (Model.ToList().Count <= 0)
{
<h3 class="col-md-offset-4"> There is no Results</h3>
}
else
{
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pk)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PartNum)
        </th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pk)
            </td>

            <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartNum)

            </td>

            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle green"></i>

                <i class="fa fa-check-circle red"></i>

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: `If statements` in razor work the same as in pure c#.. Did you actually try anything...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This :-

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pk)
            </td>

            <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PartNum)

            </td>

            <td>
              @if (item.Pk == item.PartNum){
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle green"></i>
              }else{
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle red"></i>
              }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HI,

```
                  <td>
                    @if(item.PartNum == 1 && item.Pk == 1)
                    {
                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle green"></i>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle red"></i>
                    }

                </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<i class="fa fa-check-circle @(item.Pk == item.PartNum ? "green" : "red")"></i>
```